# get artist art in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, file, mediastore

i create music player app but i have a problem ,I created a tab with an artist name and I want all the singers of the song to be in that list and the singers item to be without repetition.
I listed the artists and used this code.

```
fun makecursor(context: Context, selection: String?, selctionArgs: Array<String>?): Cursor {
    val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,//0
        MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST,//1
        MediaStore.Audio.Artists.NUMBER_OF_TRACKS, //2
    )
    val sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER
    val cursor =
        context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selctionArgs, sortOrder)
    return cursor!!
}
```

I want to get artist art but I do not know how you can help me?

Comment: You mean ALBUM_ART ?

Comment: No.i mean Artist Art

Comment: Where did you ever see that? It is not in Artists.ArtistColums.

Comment: I did not see and I wanted to see if there is a way to use id,
Get uri image artist?

Comment: As I know, an audio file has an album art embedded and not an artist art.